# What does "no device" mean when running iostat -En

Tags: solaris, disk, iostat, san

We presume to have a faulty cable that connects the SAN to a direct I/O LDOM. This is a snippet of the error when running `iostat -En`

```
   c5t60060E8007C50E000030C50E00001067d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 696633 Transport Errors: 704386
Vendor: HITACHI  Product: OPEN-V           Revision: 8001 Serial No: 504463
Size: 214.75GB <214748364800 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 6 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 1 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
```

What does `No Device: 6` mean here?

Comment: What HBA/device driver are you using?

Comment: `HBA Port WWN: 21000024ff470f2e
        OS Device Name: /dev/cfg/c2
        Manufacturer: QLogic Corp.
        Model: 371-4522-02
        Firmware Version: 8.05.00
        FCode/BIOS Version:  BIOS: 2.10; fcode: 3.06; EFI: 2.04;
        Serial Number: 0402T00-1232085736
        Driver Name: qlc
        Driver Version: 170516-5.06c
        Type: N-port
        State: online
        Supported Speeds: 2Gb 4Gb 8Gb
        Current Speed: 8Gb
        Node WWN: 20000024ff470f2e
        Link Error Statistics:
                Link Failure Count: 4386`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A search  through the [Illumos fiber-channel device code for `ENODEV`](http://src.illumos.org/source/search?q=ENODEV&path=%2Fillumos-gate%2Fusr%2Fsrc%2Futs%2Fcommon%2Fio%2Ffibre-channel%2F&project=illumos-gate) shows 13 uses of `ENODEV` in the source code that originated as OpenSolaris.

Of those instances, I suspect [this is the one most likely to cause your "No device" errors](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/io/fibre-channel/impl/fp.c#15153):

```
pd = fctl_hold_remote_port_by_pwwn(port, &pwwn);
if (pd == NULL) {
    fcio->fcio_errno = FC_BADDEV;
    return (ENODEV);
}
```

That code is in [the `fp_fcio_login()` function](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/io/fibre-channel/impl/fp.c#15036), where the code appears to be trying to login to a remote WWN.  It seems appropriate to assume a bad cable could prevent that from happening.  Note that fiber-channel error code is `FC_BADDEV`, which also seems appropriate for a bad cable.

In short, a review of the source code indicates that `ENODEV` errors are consistent a bad cable.

You can use `dTrace` to more closely identify the association if necessary.  Given that both hard and transport errors occur about 5 or 6 orders of magnitude more frequently, IMO that effort isn't necessary until the `ENODEV` errors occur after the other errors are addressed and no longer occur.

Comment: Thanks. So is 'No Device' a counter of sorts?

Comment: In this case, the number you are seeing is a count of the number of times that error code was returned when something didn't work.  But if you look at your total number of errors, you have 6 "No device" errors likely generated when your system had trouble connecting to a remote disk controller/LUN compared to 1.4 million hard and transfer errors.